# ruby simple command line script (restaurant finder)

Tags: ruby

I just finished the Ruby essential  Training course
I want to know how to write a very simple script for Restaurant Finder 
using the command line only if possible?

Features needed:
User asked to input 1- restaurant name 2- restaurant type  3- restaurant 
average price

user gets response list of the restaurants (nothing will be saved on 
file) only in the memory during the session.

also how can i let the user shows the list of added restaurants?

I want to make it as simple as possible so i can understand the language 
in a way that i missed it by the Lynda.com instructor.
Once this instructor reached the actual script building, he started 
modifying it and write lots of speedy code that confused me and made me 
almost thing like it is PHP not Ruby Video training I'm watching.

I know how to create classes and methods and using array hashes etc...
Want basic simple start to try myself how to write simple programs 
without using files to store anything

after that i will move to the next level.

Thanks.

Comment: How about you show us what you've done so far. Have you written your pseudo code in some way? Is there a plan you have thought of that will need translating to working ruby code? Otherwise it sounds like you want someone to do your homework. The community will help you i'm sure but we need something to work with apart from the question/task explanation given to you.

Comment: I didn't understand you! I finished the fundamental training, work really good with the language syntax. my problem is i need to practice with real simple ruby programs not just creating a class and defining methods and setting values to inst variables and get no real world experience.

Comment: Object Orientation is actually great and you should ideally be thinking about solving your problem by designing & creating the right classes/methods anyway. Scripts are like little controller programs whose job is to read user input and instantiate your classes and invoke methods on your objects. In the real world we strive for clean robust object oriented design. Our classes can then be invoked by command line scripts or web frameworks, doesnt matter. For now, i think you should start with showing us some pseudo code for you command line script and stuff you're struggling to convert to ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am  a newbie in Ruby too, but this is my simple implementation:

```
 class Restaurant
  attr_accessor :name, :type, :avg_price
   def initialize(name, type, avg_price)
     @name = name
     @type = type
     @avg_price = Float(avg_price)
   end   
 end

 class RestaurantsList < Array
  def read_from_keyboard
    print "Restaurant name: "
    name = gets.chomp
    print "Restaurant type: "
    type = gets.chomp
    print "Restaurant average price: "
    avg_price = gets.chomp
    self << Restaurant.new( name, type, avg_price )
  end
  def print_list
    puts sprintf("%17s %15s %s", "Name |", "Type |", "Avg price |")
    self.each { |e|  puts sprintf("%15s |%14s |%10d |", e.name, e.type, e.avg_price)}    
  end
 end

restaurants_list = RestaurantsList.new
loop do
  print "1 - add restaurant, 2 - print list, 3 - exit : "
  answer = Integer(gets.chomp)
  case answer
  when 1
    restaurants_list.read_from_keyboard
  when 2
    restaurants_list.print_list
  when 3
    break    
  end    
end
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much, your implementation is rock, as a beginner, i believe such small scripts can make me understand how the language works. just mastering syntax won't take me no where. thanks a lot i think you did a great job how many months of experience you have with ruby?

Comment: 2 months or more.
I completed _tryruby.org_, _rubymonk.com_,_rubykoans.com_ and read two books: _The Well-Grounded Rubyist_ and _Design Patterns In Ruby_. If you want learn Rails I also recommend you watch ["How to be awesome at Rails. Ryan Bigg"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=idmkGEhxqPI)